# Recursive function throws unhandled exception at 0x79B20AD2 (ucrtbased.dll)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, recursion

I write minesweeper and the current task is to write a function that would uncover the areas that have no mines neighbouring to them. In the original minesweeper if you click within the area with no mines, it would open up an area until there are mines alongside its borders. For that I wrote the function **unravel()**. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#define Str1D vector<string>
#define Str2D vector<Str1D>
#define Int1D vector<int>
#define Int2D vector<Int1D>

void unravel(Str2D &fogofwar, Int2D &display, int x, int y) {

    for (int minusrows = -1; minusrows < 2; minusrows++){ // going through the 
                                                          // neighbouring cells (+ the cell itself)
        for (int minuscolumns = -1; minuscolumns < 2; minuscolumns++){

            if (x + minusrows > 0 && y + minuscolumns > 0 && x + minusrows < fogofwar.size() && y + minuscolumns < fogofwar[0].size()){ // checking 
                                                                                                                                        // if within borders
                if (x > 0 && y > 0 && x < fogofwar.size() && y < fogofwar[0].size()) { // checking if the oririginal 
                                                                                       // values are within borders
                    fogofwar[x + minusrows][y + minuscolumns] = to_string(display[x + minusrows][y + minuscolumns]); // revealing the 
                                                                                                                     // neighbouring cells
                    if (display[x + minusrows][y + minuscolumns] == 0) { // if the cell is 0 on the display, 
                                                                         // open it and the 8 neighbouring to it cells

                        if (not (minusrows == 0 && minuscolumns == 0)) { // if it's not the same cell, of course,
                                                                         // otherwise it's an endless cycle

                            unravel(fogofwar, display, x + minusrows, y + minuscolumns);
                        }
                    }
                }                               
            }
        }
    }
}


int main() {
    int row, column, prob;
    bool running = true;


    cout << "Input width and height: ";
    cin >> row >> column;

    cout << endl << "Input mines probability (%): ";
    cin >> prob;
    cout << endl;
    srand (time(NULL));

    Int2D field(row + 1, Int1D(column + 1));
    Int2D display(row + 1, Int1D(column + 1));
    Str2D fogofwar(row + 1, Str1D(column + 1, "*"));

    field[0][0] = 0; // field of mines
    display[0][0] = 0; // display of neighbouring mines
    fogofwar[0][0] = to_string(0); // what the player will see

    for (int i = 1; i < row + 1; i++) { //assigning coordinates
        field[i][0] = i;
        display[i][0] = i;
        fogofwar[i][0] = to_string(i);
    }
    for (int j = 1; j < column + 1; j++) { //assigning coordinates
        field[0][j] = j;
        display[0][j] = j;
        fogofwar[0][j] = to_string(j);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < row + 1; i++){ // filling the field with mines
        for (int j = 1; j < column + 1; j++){
            int x = rand() % 100;
            if (x < prob) {
                field[i][j] = 1;
            }
            else{
                field[i][j] = 0;
            }

        }

    }

    cout << endl << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < row + 1; i++){ // printing field
            for (int j = 0; j < column + 1; j++){
                cout << " " << field[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }

    cout << endl << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < row + 1; i++){ // assigning the display of amount of neighbouring mines
        for (int j = 0; j < column + 1; j++){

            int count = 0;

            if (i > 0 && j > 0){

                for (int minusrows = -1; minusrows < 2; minusrows++){

                    for (int minuscolumns = -1; minuscolumns < 2; minuscolumns++){

                        if (i + minusrows > 0 && i + minusrows < row + 1 && j + minuscolumns > 0 && j + minuscolumns < column + 1){

                            if (field[i + minusrows][j + minuscolumns] == 1){

                                count++;

                            }

                        }

                    }
                }
                display[i][j] = count;
            }


            cout << " " << display[i][j] << " ";


        }
        cout << endl;
    }


    cout << endl << endl;



    while (running) {

        for (int i = 0; i < row + 1; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < column + 1; j++){
                cout << " " << fogofwar[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }

        cout << endl;

        int x, y;
        cout << endl << "Input the target cell (x, y): ";
        cin >> x >> y;
        cout << endl;

        unravel(fogofwar, display, x, y);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I delete the recursivity by changing **unravel(fogofwar, display, x + minusrows, y + minuscolumns);** to **continue;** within the function **unravel()**, it works as intended. But I need to open up the entire area where there are 0's on the display. Any way to skirt the error or fix it for good?

Comment: Run this in a debugger. Catch and inspect the exception. Note that when you recurse too deep, the stack is exhausted and the code fails, hard to tell if that is the case without a [mcve]. BTW: It would help if you hardcoded the content of your map to serve as example here. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Further, consider submitting your code to codereview.stackexchange.com once you have it working correctly.

Comment: You are checking that you don't recurse on the same cell but I don't see anything that would stop you recursing from cell A to cell B and then back to cell A again.

Comment: Probably just need to only recurse if you've changed the current cell, your check for `minusrows` and `minuscolumns` being non zero is not enough to stop the recursion

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am unable to reproduce the error with the information in question. Please try to specify the complete usecase along with what values you are getting into error with.
However, there is an obvious problem in the implementation of unravel.
You go over the same cell multiple times, until the memory exceeds total memory of course (I believe this is the point your program crashes)

You should maintain the slots already visited. You can do this in multiple ways. I am providing one of the ways to handle this.

Try the following code:-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#define Str1D vector<string>
#define Str2D vector<Str1D>
#define Int1D vector<int>
#define Int2D vector<Int1D>

void unravel(Str2D &fogofwar, Int2D &display, int x, int y, vector<vector<bool> > &visited) {

    for (int minusrows = -1; minusrows < 2; minusrows++){ // going through the
                                                          // neighbouring cells (+ the cell itself)
        for (int minuscolumns = -1; minuscolumns < 2; minuscolumns++){

            if (x + minusrows > 0 && y + minuscolumns > 0 && x + minusrows < fogofwar.size() && y + minuscolumns < fogofwar[0].size()){ // checking
                                                                                                                                        // if within borders
                if (x > 0 && y > 0 && x < fogofwar.size() && y < fogofwar[0].size()) { // checking if the oririginal
                                                                                       // values are within borders
                    if (x > 0 && y > 0 && x < visited.size() && y < visited[0].size()) {
                      cout.flush();
                    }
                    visited[x][y] = true;
                    fogofwar[x + minusrows][y + minuscolumns] = to_string(display[x + minusrows][y + minuscolumns]); // revealing the
                                                                                                                     // neighbouring cells
                    if (display[x + minusrows][y + minuscolumns] == 0) { // if the cell is 0 on the display,
                                                                         // open it and the 8 neighbouring to it cells

                        if (not visited[x + minusrows][y + minuscolumns]) { // if it's not the same cell, of course,
                                                                         // otherwise it's an endless cycle
                            unravel(fogofwar, display, x + minusrows, y + minuscolumns, visited);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


int main() {
    int row, column, prob;
    bool running = true;


    cout << "Input width and height: ";
    cin >> row >> column;

    cout << endl << "Input mines probability (%): ";
    cin >> prob;
    cout << endl;
    srand (time(NULL));

    Int2D field(row + 1, Int1D(column + 1));
    Int2D display(row + 1, Int1D(column + 1));
    Str2D fogofwar(row + 1, Str1D(column + 1, "*"));

    field[0][0] = 0; // field of mines
    display[0][0] = 0; // display of neighbouring mines
    fogofwar[0][0] = to_string(0); // what the player will see

    for (int i = 1; i < row + 1; i++) { //assigning coordinates
        field[i][0] = i;
        display[i][0] = i;
        fogofwar[i][0] = to_string(i);
    }
    for (int j = 1; j < column + 1; j++) { //assigning coordinates
        field[0][j] = j;
        display[0][j] = j;
        fogofwar[0][j] = to_string(j);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < row + 1; i++){ // filling the field with mines
        for (int j = 1; j < column + 1; j++){
            int x = rand() % 100;
            if (x < prob) {
                field[i][j] = 1;
            }
            else{
                field[i][j] = 0;
            }

        }

    }

    cout << endl << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < row + 1; i++){ // printing field
            for (int j = 0; j < column + 1; j++){
                cout << " " << field[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }

    cout << endl << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < row + 1; i++){ // assigning the display of amount of neighbouring mines
        for (int j = 0; j < column + 1; j++){

            int count = 0;

            if (i > 0 && j > 0){

                for (int minusrows = -1; minusrows < 2; minusrows++){

                    for (int minuscolumns = -1; minuscolumns < 2; minuscolumns++){

                        if (i + minusrows > 0 && i + minusrows < row + 1 && j + minuscolumns > 0 && j + minuscolumns < column + 1){

                            if (field[i + minusrows][j + minuscolumns] == 1){

                                count++;

                            }

                        }

                    }
                }
                display[i][j] = count;
            }


            cout << " " << display[i][j] << " ";


        }
        cout << endl;
    }


    cout << endl << endl;



    while (running) {

        for (int i = 0; i < row + 1; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < column + 1; j++){
                cout << " " << fogofwar[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }

        cout << endl;

        int x, y;
        cout << endl << "Input the target cell (x, y): ";
        cin >> x >> y;
        cout << endl;

        vector<vector<bool> > visited(row+1, vector<bool>(column+1, false));
        unravel(fogofwar, display, x, y, visited);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

The change is that I am maintaining a visited array, and I never go back to the spot I have already gone to before in unravel.